# Java multidimensional array concept

Tags: java, arrays

I am defining a integer multidimensional array `xyz[2][3]` and a single dimension array `y={1,2,3,4}` and then assigning `xyz[0]=y` which is working fine. Can please somebody explain me how it is allowing to store `4` elements when the size is `3`?

```
  int  xyz[][]= new int [2][3];
  int [] y = {18,9,10,6,12,15,3};
  xyz[0]=y;
  System.out.println(y.length);
  System.out.println(xyz.length);

  java.util.Arrays.sort(y);
  for(int k=0;k<xyz.length;k++)
  {
      for (int l=0;l<xyz[k].length;l++)
      {
          System.out.println("xyz[k][l] : "+xyz[k][l]);
      }
  }
```

Comment: If you use correct terms you'll have a better understanding. You cannot "define an integer multidimensional array `xyz[2][3]`" since this isn't valid Java syntax - you **create an integer multidimensional array object by `new int[2][3]`** and store the resulting reference in a variable declared for holding a reference to a two-dimensional int array: `int[][] xyz`.

Comment: int  xyz[][]= new int [2][3];
      int [] y = {18,9,10,6,12,15,3};
      xyz[0]=y;
      System.out.println(y.length);
      System.out.println(xyz.length);
      System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(y, 11));
      java.util.Arrays.sort(y);
      for(int k=0;k<xyz.length;k++)
      {
       for (int l=0;l<xyz[k].length;l++)
       {
        System.out.println("xyz[k][l] : "+xyz[k][l]);
       }
      }
This is how I have done. Can you explain the behavior?

Comment: @RanaVishwanathPratapSingh Your codes are printing the desired values, what is the issue here?

Comment: I was expecting only first 3 elements of array y but its printing all the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This declares a variable for holding a reference to a twodimensional int array. The constructor call creates a 2-by-3 int array and stores the reference in that variable. The six array elements are initialised to 0, and xyz is actually an array containing 2 references to int arrays of length 3.

```
int xyz[][]= new int [2][3];
```

Declare a variable to hold an int array, define an array object with values 18,...3 and store the reference in y.

```
int [] y = {18,9,10,6,12,15,3};
```

Replace the first reference in xyz by the reference stored in y. You now have an "array" with "rows" of unequal lengths.

```
xyz[0]=y;
```

y references an array of length 7 - the seven integers in the braces.

```
System.out.println(y.length);
```

xyz still has two reference-type elements

```
System.out.println(xyz.length);
```

Search for 11 in y - bad idea since binary search must be done on a sorted array.

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(y, 11));
```

Now sort y

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(y);
```

Obvious, no?

```
for(int k=0;k<xyz.length;k++) {
   for (int l=0;l<xyz[k].length;l++) {
        System.out.println("xyz[k][l] : "+xyz[k][l]);
   }
}
```

The first row of xyz prints in sort order - remember the sentence **Replace the first reference in xyz by the reference stored in y**, sort sorts the object pointed to by y **and the first row of xyz**.

Answer (score 2):

A two dimentional array is simply an array whose elements are arrays themselves.

If you initiaze your `xyz` array with `int[][] xyz = new int[2][3];`, you create an array of two elements and each element is an `int` array of 3 elements.

There's nothing stopping you from later assigning an `int` array of 4 elements to `xyz[0]`, just like there's nothing stopping you from assigning a 6 element `int` array to `y`. An array variable can hold a reference to any array of the same element type.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am still little confused because if I am not assigning any values it is printing the default int value which is 0 for 6 times, if I am adding any int[] to first row it is printing all the values of 1st array and 3 times 0 for other.
The output of my code is below:
xyz[k][l] : 3
xyz[k][l] : 6
xyz[k][l] : 9
xyz[k][l] : 10
xyz[k][l] : 12
xyz[k][l] : 15
xyz[k][l] : 18
xyz[k][l] : 0
xyz[k][l] : 0
xyz[k][l] : 0

Comment: @RanaVishwanathPratapSingh Can you edit you question with the exact code you are using and the output you get? It's hard you understand from this comment alone.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a multi-dimensional array is an array of arrays, and an array is just a reference.  So if you say

```
int[][] xyz = new int[2][3];
```

what you will get is an array with two *references*.  Each reference will initially be a reference to an array of three integers.  But those references all have type `int[]`, meaning they're just references to arrays of integers; there's nothing in Java that says they must always have length 3.  You can replace the reference with any `int[]`, i.e. a reference to any other array of integers--or you can replace it with `null`.

Basically, multi-dimensional arrays in Java are "ragged arrays", and the elements can all have different lengths (or be `null`).  Even if you initialize them all to the same length, they don't have to stay that way.

Answer (score 1):

Like [@Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32133133/1682559) said, when you do `int  xyz[][] = new int [2][3];` you are basically creating an array that looks like this:

- `xyz[0]` and `xyz[1]` are both `int[3]`
- `xyz[0][0]`, `xyz[0][1]` and `xyz[0][2]` are all `0` *(default value of int)*
- `xyz[1][0]`, `xyz[1][1]` and `xyz[1][2]` are all `0` *(default value of int)*

So it looks like this:

```
xyz = {
    { 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

When you are doing `xyz[0] = {18,9,10,6,12,15,3}`, you are assigning the `xyz[0]` from `int[3]` to a `int[7]`, which changes the multidimensional-array to:

- `xyz[0]` is `int[7]`
- `xyz[1]` is still `int[3]`
- `xyz[0][0]` is `18`; `xyz[0][1]` is `9`; `xyz[0][2]` is `10`; `xyz[0][3]` is `6`; `xyz[0][4]` is `12`; `xyz[0][5]` is `15`; `xyz[0][6]` is `3`
- `xyz[1][0]`, `xyz[1][1]` and `xyz[1][2]` are still `0`

And now it looks like this:

```
xyz = {
    { 18, 9, 10, 6, 12, 15, 3 },
    { 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can please somebody explain me how it is allowing to store 4 elements when the size is 3?

This is because when you declared `int  xyz[][]= new int [2][3];`, you are merely creating an array of size 2 and each of the 2 elements holds an array of 3 elements.

Visually looks like this (of course it can also be deemed as 3 rows 2 cols too):

```
{0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0}
```

The key concept here is that, 2D array in Java means an array of arrays.
Since it is an array of array, each "row" holds an array itself. Hence, you can assign any new array for each "row".

This causes the possible occurrence of **irregular arrays** in Java.

```
{0},
{0, 0},
{0, 0, 0}
```

---

**1D array of int**

```
{0, 0, 0}  //An array of int
```

---

**2D array of int**

```
{ {0,0,0}, {0,0,0}, {0,0,0}, {0,0,0} }  //An array of (1D array of int)
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, an array is an object in Java. A variable name is a reference to array and you can get the elements of array using the indexes.

Multidimensional array is an array of arrays. See [more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

In multidimensional array, you can declare array of arrays. In your example, it has been created `int` multidimensional array: `int xyz[][] = new int[2][3];` 2-by-3 means you have 2 arrays and both arrays can keep 3 `int` numbers.

When we initialize the array, **Java** provides us with the *default value(s)* inside the array. These default values depend on the *type* of array. In your example, when you access the element, for example, `xyz[1][1]` or whatever element you want in the scope of the `length` of the array, you will get `0` because the type of array is `int` and the default value of `int` is zero. So, you have 2 arrays which are situated in `xyz` and both 2 arrays have 3 zero-valued elements before assigning values by you.

When you declare and instantiate like `int xyz[][] = new int[2][3];` **Java** will automatically initialize `xyz` array with the default values like following

```
xyz[0] = {0,0,0}; 

xyz[1] = {0,0,0};
```

Then, you defined a new single dimensional array named `y`;

`int[] y = {18,9,10,6,12,15,3};`

and after creating `y` you assigned it to the zero-indexed (`xyz[0]`) array of `xyz`. `xyz[0]=y; // xyz[0] = {18,9,10,6,12,15,3};`
this means ***reassigning***. Because, when you created `xyz` array, Java automatically initializes the elements of arrays, on the other words, assigns the default values for arrays inside `xyz` then you reassign first array of `xyz` with `y`. This looks like reassigning of variables, you can create

`int a = 10;`

and then you can reassign the number to a variable `a` like this:

```
a = 45;
```

So array assignment is the similar. First Java assigns values, then you reassign. First Java assigns default values, `0s`, then you create a single dimensional array and reassign `y` to `xyz[0]`.
That’s why you are allowed to define different sizes of arrays despite of fix-sized elements.

Answer (score -2):

In 2d array  basically assume  xyz[row][col] is a matrix so in a matrix the total number of elements are equal to row*col since you have taken xyz[2][3] total number of elements are going to be 2*3=6 . you are storing four elements rest two of the elements are null . There you can store total 6 elements.
Eg xyz[4][2] = total items that can be stored 4*2=8.

Comment: The question is about arrays in Java. JAVA. J-A-V-A.

Comment: I am able to add even 10 elements no error during compile time or at run time

Comment: @RanaVishwanathPratapSingh Disregard this answer.

Comment: @laune if you go back to basics of J-A-V-A 2d arrays are best taught through matrices as it happens to give a better understanding.You are able to add 10 elements but if you try to print the array it won't.

Comment: Kindly stop posting downright wrong statements ("try to print...it won't") - or back it up by compiled and working code.

Comment: @someoneGreat I am able to print, you can try the same